# How to fix `Do not use BuildContexts across async gaps` in a StatelessWidget?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, statelesswidget

During a FireAuth process, I need to store a user instance in my `ChangeNotifier` appState.

Therefore I am meant to do that:

```dart
Provider.of<StateModel>(context, listen: false).signedIn = shokazeUser;
```

Unfortunately, I must fetch the `shokazeUser` from the remote database via an `await` modifier.
But doing so, I am exposed to the fact the context might no longer be valid.
I got the error:

> Do not use BuildContexts across async gaps.

Because I am in a `StatelessWidget` I can't do what would do in a `StatefulWidget` aka testing `mounted`.

What to do then?

My code's as follows:

```dart
 Future<String?> _authUser(BuildContext context, LoginData data) {
    debugPrint('Name: ${data.name}, Password: ${data.password}');

    return auth
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: data.name, password: data.password)
        .then((credential) async {
      try {
        final user = credential.user;

        if (user == null) {
          return 'Password does not match';
        } else {
          // == Tell the app we just signed in

          try {
            final shokazeUser = await shokaze.User.getFromId(user.uid);
            if (shokazeUser == null) {
              return "Unable to fetch user from database";
            }
            Provider.of<StateModel>(context, listen: false).signedIn =
                shokazeUser;
          } catch (e) {
            return "Error while fetching user from database: $e";
          }
          return null;
        }
      } catch (e) {
        return 'User not exists';
      }
    }).catchError((e) {
      if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
        debugPrint('The password provided is too weak.');
      } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
        debugPrint('The account already exists for that email.');
      } else {
        debugPrint(e.toString());
      }

      return Future<String?>.error(e);
    });
```

Comment: Just change it to a StatefulWidget then?

Comment: Sure, this is my fallback. But ain't it be any better solution?

Comment: No, not yet. Rumor says that mounted check might be coming to StatelessWidgets. But, I see no reasonable reason why not make it into a StatefulWidget.

Comment: Yep. I agree there's nothing bad. Let me turn in into a stateful widget. But if any one has better idea, please fell free to tell us. Thanks for stopping by and help.